# Fetch newly added documents from elastic search on nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

If i have a new document added to an index (say assets), how do i fetch that data from nodejs? I needed like a listener, when a new document is added to elastic search, i want to fetch that document.Can someone help me?